# Não consigo ter sucesso ao efetuar uma requisição via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu pego no meu JS o mês que o usuário escolheu no select do HTML, se caso o valor mês foi definido ele executa a função Filtra_data_Banco conforme o valor, se não eu defino que o valor será "m", mas ele não faz a requisição e fica apenas caindo na condição de erro. Eu esperava que ele me mostra-se "ok".

Código:

**ajax.js**

```
$(function(){
  mostraMesSelect();
  var mes = pegaMesSelect();

  if(typeof mes == "undefined"){
    Filtra_data_Banco("m");
  }else{
    Filtra_data_Banco(mes);
  }
});

function Filtra_data_Banco(valor){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax-FiltrosDashboard.php',
    data:{
        mesSelect:valor
    }, 
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        console.log("Erro indesperado "+ valor);
    }
  });
}

function pegaMesSelect(){
  var mesValue = $("#mesSelect");

  mesValue.change(function(){
    console.log(mesValue.val());

    return mesValue;
  });
}

function mostraMesSelect(){
  $("#mesSelect").change(function(){
    var mesText = $("#mesSelect option:selected").text();

    $("#mesSelecionado").html('<h2 class="text-center">'+mesText+'</h2>');
  });
}
```

**ajax-FiltrosDashboard.php**

```
<?php

if($_POST['mesSelect']){
  echo json_encode($_POST['mesSelect']);
}
```

Saída do Console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mude json_encoder para json_encode

Comment: Mesmo assim, sem sucesso

Comment: Tente debuggar pelo navegador(Ferramenta desenvolvedor), verifique se na aba console é exibido algum erro. Você também pode visualizar na aba network se a página ajax-FiltrosDashboard.php foi chamada corretamente e quais parametros foram enviados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente precisamos verificar qual erro está sendo gerado na requisição.

A *URL* está correta? O caminho está correto?

Substitua sua função Ajax por:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'ajax-FiltrosDashboard.php',
 data:{ "mesSelect": valor }, 
 dataType: "json",
 success:function(data){
  console.log(data);
 },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    },
});
```

E como já foi dito, no arquivo *.php* mude para:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['mesSelect'])){
    echo json_encode($_POST['mesSelect']);
}
```

Perceba que seu *request* contém: `dataType: "json"`.

De acordo com a documentação do *jQuery*:

> Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. (...)
>   The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown.

O que isso quer dizer? Seu request está retornando JSON inválido.

**Solução**: Tenha certeza de que o código do servidor (PHP) está retornando um JSON válido.

Comment: 1- O caminho está correto;
2- Substitui o ajax;
3- mudei para json_encode

Rest: Ele retornou 200 no console do browser.

Comment: E a resposta do php é qual? em network clique na requisição e a na aba response para ter acesso

Comment: @AlexandreVieiradeSouza Veja minha edição.

Comment: era isso mesmo, valeu